# Spring Security make username and password auth at specific path

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

my spring-boot project is based on REST and JWT authentication. Now I would like to disable the JWT auth for a specific path and instead of it authenticate by simple username and password. Is it achievable ?

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/jwt/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable();
    }
```

I want to add auth by username and password for example to "/api/data/**".

EDIT:

My first config with `@Order(1)`

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("abc").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/data/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

It works, but when the request with correct credentials to api/data/** is executed, the `jwtAuthenticationFilter()` fires also.

Answer (score 0):

Implement AuthenticationProvider class for custom authentication using username and password. Then use the authentication provider like -

```
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(
            @NotNull AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(
            HttpSecurity http) throws
            Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/api/data/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .and()
           .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
```